# Android Espresso: Testing Preferences (multiple ListViews)

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I'm trying to test my `SettingsActivity` class, but I keep getting a `AmbiguousViewMatcherException`.

Here's my testcase:

```
@Test
public void whenHospitalSettingEmpty_shouldDisplaySummary() throws Exception {
    Resources res = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getResources();

    mPreferenceEditor.putString(
            res.getString(R.string.activity_settings_hospital_key),
            "");

    mActivityTestRule.launchActivity(null);

    String expected = res.getString(R.string.activity_settings_hospital_summary);

    onData(allOf(
            is(instanceOf(Preference.class)),
            withKey(res.getString(R.string.activity_settings_hospital_key)),
            withSummary(R.string.activity_settings_hospital_summary),
            withTitle(R.string.activity_settings_hospital_title)))
            .onChildView(withText(expected))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));

}
```

Here's the log output:

```
android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
Problem views are marked with '****MATCHES****' below.

View Hierarchy:
...
+------->LinearLayout{id=16909142, res-name=headers, visibility=VISIBLE, width=600, height=887, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+-------->ListView{id=16908298, res-name=list, visibility=VISIBLE, width=536, height=823, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=32.0, y=32.0, child-count=0} ****MATCHES******
|
+-------->FrameLayout{id=16909143, res-name=list_footer, visibility=VISIBLE, width=536, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=32.0, y=855.0, child-count=0}
|
+------>RelativeLayout{id=16909146, res-name=button_bar, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+------->AppCompatButton{id=16909147, res-name=back_button, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=Tilbage, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+-------->AppCompatButton{id=16909148, res-name=skip_button, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=Spring over, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+-------->AppCompatButton{id=16909149, res-name=next_button, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=Næste, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+----->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=600, height=887, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
|
+------>ListView{id=16908298, res-name=list, visibility=VISIBLE, width=600, height=887, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=true, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=12} ****MATCHES******
|
+------->AppCompatTextView{id=16908310, res-name=title, visibility=VISIBLE, width=584, height=35, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=8.0, y=0.0, text=Synkronisering, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
...
```

For some reason the `onData()` matches two `ListView`s, but I just can't figure out how to prevent this, because I don't understand where the first `ListView` comes from.

Here's my `preference.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/activity_settings_sync_category_title"
        android:key="@string/activity_settings_sync_category_key">

        <SwitchPreference
            android:key="@string/activity_settings_sync_key"
            android:summary="@string/activity_settings_sync_summary"
            android:title="@string/activity_settings_sync_title"
            android:defaultValue="true"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/activity_settings_site_category_title"
        android:key="@string/activity_settings_site_category_key"
        android:summary="@string/activity_settings_site_category_summary">


        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="@string/activity_settings_hospital_key"
            android:title="@string/activity_settings_hospital_title"
            android:summary="@string/activity_settings_hospital_summary"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/activity_settings_hospital_dialog_title"
            android:dialogMessage="@string/activity_settings_hospital_dialog_message"
            android:inputType="textCapWords" />

        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="@string/activity_settings_department_key"
            android:title="@string/activity_settings_department_title"
            android:summary="@string/activity_settings_department_summary"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/activity_settings_department_dialog_title"
            android:dialogMessage="@string/activity_settings_department_dialog_message"
            android:inputType="textCapWords" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/activity_settings_notification_ringtone_category_title"
        android:key="@string/activity_settings_notification_ringtone_category_key">


        <RingtonePreference
            android:key="@string/activity_settings_notification_ringtone_key"
            android:title="@string/activity_settings_notification_ringtone_title"
            android:summary="@string/activity_settings_notification_ringtone_summary"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/activity_settings_notification_ringtone_dialog_title"
            android:dialogMessage="@string/activity_settings_notification_ringtone_dialog_message"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/activity_settings_dicom_category_title"
        android:key="@string/activity_settings_dicom_category_key">

        <SwitchPreference
                android:key="@string/activity_settings_dicom_worklist_key"
                android:title="@string/activity_settings_dicom_worklist_title"
                android:summary="@string/activity_settings_dicom_worklist_summary" />

            <!--<EditTextPreference-->
                <!--android:key="dcmwl_ae_title_preference"-->
                <!--android:title="@string/pref_dicom_settings_worklist_ae_title"-->
                <!--android:dialogMessage="@string/pref_dicom_settings_worklist_ip_dialog_text"-->
                <!--android:dialogTitle="@string/pref_dicom_settings_worklist_ip_dialog_title"-->
                <!--android:dependency="dcmwl_enable"/>-->
            <!--<EditTextPreference-->
                <!--android:defaultValue="10.0.0.2"-->
                <!--android:key="dcmwl_ip_preference"-->
                <!--android:title="@string/pref_dicom_settings_worklist_ip"-->
                <!--android:dependency="dcmwl_enable" />-->
            <!--<EditTextPreference-->
                <!--android:key="dcmwl_port_preference"-->
                <!--android:title="@string/pref_dicom_settings_worklist_port"-->
                <!--android:dependency="dcmwl_enable"/>-->

        <SwitchPreference
            android:key="@string/activity_settings_dicom_pacs_key"
            android:title="@string/activity_settings_dicom_pacs_title"
            android:summary="@string/activity_settings_dicom_pacs_summary"/>

            <!--<EditTextPreference-->
                <!--android:key="pacs_ae_title_preference"-->
                <!--android:title="@string/pref_dicom_settings_pacs_ae_title"-->
                <!--android:dependency="pacs_enable"/>-->
            <!--<EditTextPreference-->
                <!--android:defaultValue="10.0.0.2"-->
                <!--android:key="pacs_ip_preference"-->
                <!--android:title="@string/pref_dicom_settings_pacs_ip"-->
                <!--android:dependency="pacs_enable"/>-->
            <!--<EditTextPreference-->
                <!--android:key="pacs_port_preference"-->
                <!--android:title="@string/pref_dicom_settings_pacs_port"-->
                <!--android:dependency="pacs_enable"/>-->

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/activity_settings_debug_category_title"
        android:key="@string/activity_settings_debug_category_key">

        <SwitchPreference
            android:key="@string/activity_settings_debug_key"
            android:summary="@string/activity_settings_debug_summary"
            android:title="@string/activity_settings_debug_title"
            android:defaultValue="false"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**Update:**
Tried to modify the proposed solution from first answer like this:

```
private static Matcher<View> withResName(final String resName) {

        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("with res-name: " + resName);
                Timber.d("Resourcename: ", resName);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
                Timber.d("View ID: ", view.getId());
                String matchableResName = view.getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId());
                return !TextUtils.isEmpty(matchableResName) && matchableResName.equals(resName);
            }
        };
    }
```

The test looks like this now:

```
@Test
    public void whenHospitalSettingEmpty_shouldDisplaySummary() throws Exception {
        Resources res = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getResources();

        mPreferenceEditor.putString(
                res.getString(R.string.activity_settings_hospital_key),
                "").commit();

        mActivityTestRule.launchActivity(null);

        String expected = res.getString(R.string.activity_settings_hospital_summary);

//        onView(withText(expected)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

        onData(allOf(
                is(instanceOf(Preference.class)),
                withKey(res.getString(R.string.activity_settings_hospital_key)),
                withSummary(R.string.activity_settings_hospital_summary),
                withTitle(R.string.activity_settings_hospital_title)))
                .onChildView(withText(expected))
                .inAdapterView(withParent(not(withResName("headers"))))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));


    }
```

But it still doesn't work. The log output looks like this:

```
...
I/TestRunner: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
 Unable to find resource ID #0xffffffff
    at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceEntryName(Resources.java:2127)
    at com.conhea.smartgfr.preferences.SettingsActivityTest$2.matchesSafely(SettingsActivityTest.java:153)
    at com.conhea.smartgfr.preferences.SettingsActivityTest$2.matchesSafely(SettingsActivityTest.java:143)
    at org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher.matches(TypeSafeMatcher.java:65)
    at org.hamcrest.core.IsNot.matches(IsNot.java:25)
    at android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers$26.matchesSafely(ViewMatchers.java:892)
    at android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers$26.matchesSafely(ViewMatchers.java:883)
    at org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher.matches(TypeSafeMatcher.java:65)
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `PreferenceCategory` will internally create `ListView`. Hence, you'd end up having multiple `AdapterView`s in your hierarchy, thus `AmbiguousViewMatcherException` happens.

As long as you do **not** possess with the `id` of those `ListView`s, you cannot perform matching with `ViewMatcher.withId()`. Thus, you have to create a custom matcher based on something significant between those `ListView`s.

Unfortunately, those `ListView`s have same attributes, thus you have to perform matching on the parent level. The parent of those `ListView`s is a `LinearLayout`. As you may notice, one of them (actually the one that you are not interested in) has an attribute `res-name=headers`.

This will give you a hint to perform matching on a `ListView`, that has a parent, which resource name is **not** *"headers"*.

Let's try to do that in Espresso language. Firsts, let's write a matcher, that matches a `View` with a specific resource name:

```
    class ResourceNameMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher {

      private final String resName;

      public ResourceNameMatcher(String resName) {
        this.resName = resName;
      }

      @Override protected boolean matchesSafely(View item) {
        Resources resources = item.getResources();
        String matchableResName = resources.getResourceName(item.getId());
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(matchableResName) && matchableResName.equals(resName);
      }

      @Override public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("with res-name: " + resName);
      }
    }
```

Now, let's perform matching on a `View`, that has **not** particular resource name:

```
      onData(allOf(
                   Matchers.is(instanceOf(Preference.class),
                   ... // other matchers here )))
          .onChildView(withText(expected))
          .inAdapterView(withParent(not(new ResourceNameMatcher("headers"))))
          .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Note, this is just a sketch code, which may not work, as long as I have not tested it. Nevertheless, the concept should work.

Comment: This doesn't work. item.getId() is not returning an ID. For some reason the android.R.id.headers id is hidden. This is really strange because in the layout inspector I can see that the linearlayout has an ID named headers and in the debugging output I can see the integer value.

Comment: Instead of `item.getId()` perform `resources.getIdentifier("headers", "id", "android")`

Comment: getIdentifier() was part of the solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution for testing my SettingsActivity.

The test:

```
@Test
public void whenHospitalSettingEmpty_shouldDisplaySummary() throws Exception {
    Resources res = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getResources();

    // Set the hospital preferencevalue to empty
    mPreferenceEditor.putString(
            res.getString(R.string.activity_settings_hospital_key),
            "").commit();

    // Launch activity
    mActivityTestRule.launchActivity(null);

    // When hospital value is empty we want to display the summary from our string ressources
    // instead of our preferencevalue
    onPreferenceRow(allOf(
                withKey(res.getString(R.string.activity_settings_hospital_key)),
                withSummary(R.string.activity_settings_hospital_summary)))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

My helper methods:

```
...

private static Matcher<View> withResName(final String resName) {

    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with res-name: " + resName);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            int identifier = view.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "id", "android");
            return !TextUtils.isEmpty(resName) && (view.getId() == identifier);
        }
    };
}

private static DataInteraction onPreferenceRow(Matcher<? extends Object> datamatcher) {

    DataInteraction interaction = onData(datamatcher);

    return interaction
        .inAdapterView(allOf(
            withId(android.R.id.list),
            not(withParent(withResName("headers")))));
}
```